# Google Play Music downloaded music not storing on SD card

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, google-play-music

I have a Motorola Moto G3 with a measly 4GB of storage, so I bought a 32GB SD card. I installed it as **internal** storage. I have a subscription to Google Play Music and spend a lot of time without an internet connection, so I download a lot of music. I set GPM's storage location to the SD card, but when I try to install apps, it says I'm out of storage even though there's plenty of space left on the SD card. I took a look at the storage and GPM is using practically all the internal storage.

[image]

[image]

I'm also confused because the SD card shows different amounts used in different menus. I need to either get GPM to store on the SD card like it should or get apps to install anyway.

I guess apps can't install if you don't have internal storage free?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are on Andorid Marshmallow (6.0.x).

When you put that SD card to your device it should have prompted how want you use the new SD card: as a portable device or internal storage.

So I think you have choosed the portable device option.

In this case to use your SD card as internal storage follow these steps:

1. Make sure you have made a **backup** from your SD card **before** the formating.
2. Go to <kbd>Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Storage</kbd>
3. Select your `SD Card` -> tap the `three-dot menu` -> <kbd>Settings</kbd>
4. Select <kbd>Format as internal</kbd> -> <kbd>Erase & Format</kbd>
5. Your `SD Card` will be formatted as internal storage
6. **Reboot** the phone *

*: This is very important, otherwise you may end up frustrated with issues like MTP not showing SD card, some apps not working properly, etc.

**P.S.**: If you are on Android Lollipop (5.1.x) you have to root your decvice and use 3rd party apps to move app data from internal storage to external storage (SD card).

Comment: I definitely set it up as internal. I put a screenshot to show.